# We’ve wanted for a long time for these programs to be recognized

Tags: verbs

A news article titled "[Adoption programs are doing wonders for WAHS](http://www.havasunews.com/news/adoption-programs-are-doing-wonders-for-wahs/article_e2745316-e50d-11e6-8864-6bf4d031d7f8.html)" starts as follows:

> PetSmart Charities on Thursday recognized two adoption programs of the Western Arizona Humane Society with a check for $5,000.
>
> The Humane Society’s “Senior Animal Program” and “Buddy Program” received what Executive Director Patty Gillmore said was long-sought recognition.
>
> “This is huge for us,” Gillmore said. “**We’ve wanted for a long time for these programs to be recognized.**" ...

Is the last sentence that the executive director was quoted as saying well-formed English?

Also, how about these variants?

> (1) For a long time, we've wanted for these programs to be recognized.
>
> (2) For a long time, we've wanted these programs to be recognized.
>
> (3) We've wanted, for a long time, these programs to be recognized.

Comment: It is not uncommon in writing to have the temporal phrase appear after the verb as it does in the quoted example, separating the verb from its complement. The sentence is well-formed in that respect, although the repeated **for** is marginal.  "We've wanted ... **for** these programs to be recognized".  Your variants are well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

We've wanted for a long time for these programs to be recognized.

It's a well-formed sentence. I think any change in the sentence will derogate from the quality and real meaning of the sentence.

You cannot omit "for" from the phrasal verb "want for" that has a different meaning from the meaning of the verb "want".

The phrase is used to mean to lack or need something, whereas the verb want means to desire, wish, or have a feeling to possess something.  Hence the phrase want for and the mere verb want are not at all interchangeable. Look at the foĺlowing sentences to find the difference between them:

We don't want for helpers around here (= don't lack/need).

We don't want helpers around here (don't desire).

Comment: I thought that "want for" meaning "lack" was used in a negative sentence as in your example. Also, is it possible to add a to-infinitive clause after "want for"? _We don't want for helpers to be around here_

Comment: @JK2, Yes, we can.